# Stuck on a grub rescue cannot boot into WIndows10

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, boot, grub, mbr

I had Windows 10 + Ubuntu Mate Dual boot installed.
I deleted the Ubuntu Mate partition from Device Manager and after the restart, i stuck in the `grub rescue`.

What I've tried:

1. tried to do ls (hd0,msdos) for every partition none was found
2. Booted Windows 10 from a USB drive and tried to do

```
  bootrec /fixmbr 
  bootrec /fixboot 
  bootrec /scanos 
  bootrec /rebuildbcd
```

always returns Total Identified WIndows installation: 0

3. I even decided to format my `C` drive where Windows was installed and reinstall Windows, nothing helped it is still booting into grub rescue

I've tried most of the recommendations and nothing helped and I don't know what to do.
Any help will be appreciated.

The output from list volume in case if this helps

[image]

Comment: was the install successful ?? boot to recovery > get the drive letter on which win is installed using disk part > do : bcdboot <drive name>:\windows >

Comment: have you tried linux boot repair tool ??

Comment: I've tried boot-repair after restarting it boots again into `grub rescue`